# Hide logo on scroll, doesn't trigger on scroll back to top

Tags: jquery, scroll, window, hide, show

I'm trying to create a function that hides a site's logo when the user starts scrolling the page and then shows it again when the user scrolls back to top. Triggering the hide part work is a breeze, but for some reason the top event is not triggered when scrolling back. By running a console log for the position I see that it reaches 0. What am I missing?

```
$(window).scroll( function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 0 ) {
        hide_logo();
    }
    else {
        show_logo();
    }
});

function show_logo() {
    if ( $('header').offset().top < 10 ) {
        $('body').animate({ marginTop: 180 }, 400);
        $('header').animate({ marginTop: 0 }, 400});
    }
}

function hide_logo() {
    if ( $('header').offset().top < 10 ) {
        $('body').animate({ marginTop: 90 }, 400);
        $('header').animate({ marginTop: -90 }, 400 });
    }
}
```

Edit: solved, see updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jQ8JD/

Maybe the are other js errors preventing the show to execute (view the error count in the developers console) or there is an error inside `show_logo()` function.

Comment: Thanks! Both functions actually ran fine but the hide_logo() kept stacking up minus margins to the elements (in order to hide them) and so even if show_logo() triggered they were placed farther up in the document than they should for when returning. Solved now, see update.